# Script to add characters at the beginning of every line in a code block?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a markdown file with some code blocks in it, formatted like this:

````
This is some texte.

```
// Some code
var foo = 42;
```

Some more texte.
````

What I'm trying to do is to add the letters 'A> ' at the beginning of every line that is a code block. So the output for the previous file would be:

````
This is some texte.

A> ```
A> // Some code
A> var foo = 42;
A> ```

Some more texte.
````

How can I do that? I tried making a bash script using grep, with no success.

Comment: It would be helpful if you made it clearly exactly what marks a code block beginning and end. Is it just one backtick, or three, or any number?

Comment: @TomFenech It's 3 backtick that starts and ends a block quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done with a perl one-liner like this:

```
perl -pne '$_ = "A> $_" if /^`{3}/ ... /^`{3}/' file
```

This prepends the string `"A> "` onto ranges between lines starting with three backticks.

#### edit

In order to edit your file in-place, the easiest method is this:

```
perl -pne '$_ = "A> $_" if /^`{3}/ ... /^`{3}/' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

i.e. redirect the output to a new file `tmp` and then overwrite `file` if the command has executed succesfully.

Comment: @pimpampoum see my edit for a way to overwrite your original file

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -E 's/(.*)/A> \1/g' textfile.txt > new_textfile.txt
```

where textfile.txt contains your code.

Comment: I don't see any mention to backtick in this expression, so I'm not sure how this can work.

Comment: Ah my bad, I didn't realize that you only needed it for the code between the backticks .

Answer (score 0):

Using awk:

````
awk '!c && /```/{c=NR} c{$0 = "A> " $0} c<NR && /```/{c=0}1' file
This is some texte.

A> ```
A> // Some code
A> var foo = 42;
A> ```

Some more texte.
````

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

````
awk '/```/{ sub(/^/, "A> "); print; while (getline) { sub(/^/, "A> "); print; if (/```/) next; }  }; 1' file
````

Output:

````
This is some texte.

A> ```
A> // Some code
A> var foo = 42;
A> ```

Some more texte.
````

Answer (score 0):

using `sed`:

````
sed '/^```/,/^```/s/^/A> /' file_in > file_out
````

This should have exacty the output as you specified.

Comment: This might not work as expected if there are two or more blocks.

Comment: Let it be 100 such blocks, it still should work.
range for substitute `/begin_pattern/,/end_pattern/` will work for as many bloks will be there in the input file.

Comment: I had the assumption that such addressing might be greedy. And I'm not sure if `sed` does that non-greedy behaviour in all versions. But ok, your code worked with multiple blocks but I had to remove some backslash quoting as it didn't work for me.

Comment: Might be, removing the backslashes then, did not try and was not sure about them and added `^` for search pattern to make them not greedy.